# Summing values from array and get a double

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop, vector

I'm trying to run this loop to get `n` to be a decimal number. However, if I call values from the vector `p`, `n` also becomes a vector.

How do I fix that?

lamb=linspace(400,800,num=20)

```
for k in 1/lamb:
    AR2 = 1.55
    p =  [-0.003396, 0.6518, 66.01, 2435]
    n = 0.00

    for i in range(0, 3): 
        n = n + AR2+ p[i]/k**(10-i)
```

Comment: What are `n` and `lamb` referring to?

Comment: sorry, nyellow is actually n while lamb=linspace(400,800,num=20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linspace(400,800,num=20)` is an array. Performing operations on it does it element-wise. For example:

```
>>> linspace(400,800,num=20)
array([ 400.        ,  421.05263158,  442.10526316,  463.15789474,
    484.21052632,  505.26315789,  526.31578947,  547.36842105,
    568.42105263,  589.47368421,  610.52631579,  631.57894737,
    652.63157895,  673.68421053,  694.73684211,  715.78947368,
    736.84210526,  757.89473684,  778.94736842,  800.        ])

>>> 2 + linspace(400,800,num-20)
array([ 402.        ,  423.05263158,  444.10526316,  465.15789474,
    486.21052632,  507.26315789,  528.31578947,  549.36842105,
    570.42105263,  591.47368421,  612.52631579,  633.57894737,
    654.63157895,  675.68421053,  696.73684211,  717.78947368,
    738.84210526,  759.89473684,  780.94736842,  802.        ])
```

You can't just add or multiply an array by floats and get a float back. THe problem isn't with `p`, it's `linspace`

Comment: Sorry - I should have said that it's all in a bigger loop: for k in 1/lamb:

Comment: Ahh - now I understand...I was calling lamb but actually I should have called k! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If I set `lamb` and `AR2` to be numbers then I don't see `n` becoming an array i.e

```
AR2 = 1.55
p =  [-0.003396, 0.6518, 66.01, 2435]
n = 0.00
lamb = 0.97
AR2 = 1

for i in range(0, 3): 
    n = n + AR2+ p[i]*lamb**(10-i)
    print(n)
```

Returns:

```
 0.9974957076650648 
 4930143116961103
 55.22791346817842
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I got the same result. The problem is that lamb=linspace() is an array, not a single value. See above answer